# Grails Domain - Reserved Keyword Names

Tags: mysql, grails, codenarc

So I've finally introduced `codenarc` into my project's build process and I'm getting the following warning - `GrailsDomainReservedSqlKeywordName`.

The problem is that I have quite a few of these warnings, namely because I've named quite a few domain fields as `data`. For example

```
class FormData {

  Long data
  static constraints = {
    data nullable: true
  }
  ...
```

The effect of this according to `codenarc` is

> Naming a domain class (or its field) with such a keyword causes SQL
>   schema creation errors and/or redundant table/column name mappings.

**My question is**: Should I now rename all my `data` properties and if so, how best to do it (perhaps using database migration)?

I'm just wondering why the Grails documentation did not warn against using these reserved keywords. Perhaps they should.

Comment: grails don't know about which dialect you will use that's why it didn't do that job and left it over to dialect to say whether some column name etc are valid as per db or not.

Comment: Though codenarc is just warning you about this and not forcing to remove this. You may use db migration but without changing your domain field names by using data column: 'some_other_name'. Even after this if codenarc says problem then codenarc needs some upgrades specific to grails :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to prevent this with Grails. Add a mapping in your `FormData` domain class like this:

```
class FormData {

    Long data

    static constraints = {
        data nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        data column: '`data`'
    }
}
```

Grails/Hibernate allows you to use backticks (`) to allowing the name to be escaped and now you don't have to write any database migration. You can simply be using your `data` field as is.

Comment: @downvoter What is the problem here? Can you please explain if that helped or not instead of downvoting.